# Why compress this javascript file cause error

Tags: javascript, jquery, compression

I use Jquery , and change many compress tool but still cause error "it dont know function I created  in this file"

http://gist.github.com/586338

help me !!!

This file run fine , dont have a error if it dont compress

Comment: Post your compressed code as well. It's impossible to know what the issue is if we don't know how it was compressed. It may be as simple as removing the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You should have stated in your question which compress tool you used. Also, knowing what it was compressed to could have helped as well. Using [this](http://jscompress.com/), it was compressed to:

```
//...

$(function(){
//...
      /**
       *    CENTER
       */
      $.fn.equalWmargin = function(){
            $(this).css('left',($(window).width()-$(this).outerWidth())/2);
      }
      $.fn.equalHmargin = function(){
            $(this).css('top',($(window).height()-$(this).outerHeight())/2);
      }
      $.fn.equalMargin = function(){
            $(this).css('top',($(window).height()-$(this).outerHeight())/2);
            $(this).css('left',($(window).width()-$(this).outerWidth())/2);
      };
});
```

You didn't have those last center functions inside the right scope. Here it is compressed:

```
$(function(){$("#flashMessage,#authMessage").hide();$("#flashMessage,#authMessage").css('top',0).css('left',0);$("#flashMessage,#authMessage").slideDown('fast');setTimeout(function(){$("#flashMessage,#authMessage").slideUp('slow')},10000);$("form").submit(function(){$(this).find(":submit").attr('disabled','disabled');});$("<div/>",{"id":"ajaxloading","style":"background-color:yellow;padding:7px 15px;border-radius: 5px;-moz-border-radius: 5px;-webkit-border-radius: 5px;box-shadow: 5px 5px 2px black;  -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #CCC; -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #CCC;z-index:999;"}).appendTo("body");$("#ajaxloading").hide();$("#ajaxloading").css('position','fixed').html("<b>Now Loading ...</b>").css('left',($(window).width()-$("#ajaxloading").outerWidth())/2).css('top',($(window).height()-$("#ajaxloading").outerWidth())/2);});$(function(){$.fn.popBox=function(options){var target=options.target;var trigger=this;function _showOverlay(target,trigger){$(trigger).click(function(){$('<div>',{id:'overlay',css:{width:"100%",height:"100%",left:0,top:0,position:"fixed","z-index":1000,"background-color":"#222",opacity:0.3}}).hide().appendTo(document.body).fadeIn(100);$(target).fadeIn(100);return false;});}
function _hideOverlay(target){$('body').delegate('#overlay','click',function(){$('#overlay').fadeOut(100,function(){$(target).fadeOut(100);$(this).remove();});});}
_showOverlay(target,trigger);_hideOverlay(target);};$.fn.checkedAll=function(){$(this).click(function(){form=$(this).closest('form');if(form.find('input:checkbox').attr('checked')==""){$(form).find('input:checkbox').attr('checked','checked');}else{$(form).find('input:checkbox').attr('checked','');}
return false;});};$.fn.previewImg=function(options){var options=$.extend({'removeOld':true,'event':'click'},options);var xOffset=5;var yOffset=15;if(options.event=='hover'){$(this).hover(function(e){_showPreview(e);},function(){this.title=this.t;$("#screenshot").remove();});$(this).mousemove(function(e){$("#screenshot").css("top",(e.pageY+yOffset)+"px").css("left",(e.pageX+xOffset)+"px");});}
if(options.event=='click'){$(this).bind('click',_showPreview);}
$(this).click(function(){return false});function _showPreview(e){if(options.event=='click'&&options.removeOld==false){idscreenshot=Math.floor(Math.random()*30000);}else{$("#screenshot").remove();idscreenshot='screenshot'};e.currentTarget.t=e.currentTarget.title;e.currentTarget.title="";var c=(e.currentTarget.t!="")?"<br/><div style='text-align:center'>"+e.currentTarget.t+"</div>":"";$("body").append("<div id='"+idscreenshot+"' class='screenshot' class='position:absolute;border:1px solid #ccc;background:#333;padding:5px;display:none;color:#fff;'><img src='"+e.currentTarget.href+"' alt='url preview' />"+c+"</div>");$("#"+idscreenshot).css({position:"absolute",border:"1px solid #ccc",background:"#333","box-shadow":"5px 5px 2px #CCC","-moz-box-shadow":"2px 2px 2px #CCC","-webkit-box-shadow":"4px 4px 4px #CCC",padding:"5px",display:'none',color:"#fff",cursor:"pointer"}).css("top",(e.pageY-xOffset)+"px").css("left",(e.pageX+yOffset)+"px").fadeIn("fast");$("#"+idscreenshot).click(function(){$(this).remove();});}}
$.fn.tooltip=function(){xOffset=5;yOffset=10;if($(this).attr('title').length>0){$(this).hover(function(e){idtooltip=Math.floor(Math.random()*30000);this.t=this.title;this.title='';$("body").append("<p id='"+idtooltip+"'>"+this.t+"</p>");$("#"+idtooltip).css({position:"absolute",border:"1px solid #333",background:"#f7f5d1","box-shadow":"5px 5px 2px #CCC","-moz-box-shadow":"2px 2px 2px #CCC","-webkit-box-shadow":"2px 2px 2px #CCC",padding:"2px 5px",color:"#333",display:"none"}).css("top",(e.pageY-xOffset)+"px").css("left",(e.pageX+yOffset)+"px").fadeIn(100);},function(){this.title=this.t;$("#"+idtooltip).fadeOut('100',function(){$(this).remove();});});$(this).mousemove(function(e){$("#"+idtooltip).css("top",(e.pageY-xOffset)+"px").css("left",(e.pageX+yOffset)+"px");});}};$.fn.equalWmargin=function(){$(this).css('left',($(window).width()-$(this).outerWidth())/2);}
$.fn.equalHmargin=function(){$(this).css('top',($(window).height()-$(this).outerHeight())/2);}
$.fn.equalMargin=function(){$(this).css('top',($(window).height()-$(this).outerHeight())/2);$(this).css('left',($(window).width()-$(this).outerWidth())/2);};});
```